# When is semaphore initialized with value 0?

Tags: c

I am seeing a value of 0 being used in a piece of code. We use a value of 1 for a binary semaphore and a value of N for a counting semaphore. Somehow the value of 0 isn't making sense to me.

```
/* Initialise the semaphore to be blocked. */

sem_t sem; 
sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
```

The code is in C programming.
Then as usual we have sem_wait, sem_post and sem_destroy in other places within the code.

If using either 0 or 1  is fine, then why doesn't this program run -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t mutex;

void* thread(void* arg)
{
        //wait
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        printf("\nEntered..\n");

        //critical section
        sleep(4);

        //signal
        printf("\nJust Exiting...\n");
        sem_post(&mutex);
}


int main()
{
        sem_init(&mutex, 0, 0);
        pthread_t t1,t2;
        pthread_create(&t1,NULL,thread,NULL);
        sleep(2);
        pthread_create(&t2,NULL,thread,NULL);
        pthread_join(t1,NULL);
        pthread_join(t2,NULL);
        sem_destroy(&mutex);
        return 0;
}
```

The same would run if sem_init was done with sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

Comment: What code is this and what language are you using (C or C++)? There's no indication what library you're using, where `ctx` comes from or contains, or anything that would allow us to know anything about the code in question.

Comment: This edit is borderline inappropriate, possibly over the border. Changing questions to invalidate existing answers is discouraged—it is counter to Stack Overflow’s goal of being a durable repository of questions and **matching** answers, and it is unfair to the people who already answered, as their correct and useful initial answers may be voted down by latecomers who think they do not answer the current question. If your initial question did not elicit the information you sought, it is better to enter a new question (and possibly to delete the original questions).

Comment: actually wanted to explain with another piece of code by replying to their comments, but was not possible to format it there. so only option i had was to paste it alongside my 
 initial question where it was possible to format it. Not meant to invalidate their initial answers in anyway. But I understand what you mean. matching answers to questions !

Comment: @badri At the point when you made edits to the question which invalidated one or more answers, the correct course of action was to create a new question. Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against Stack Exchange policy (even when your original question wasn't what you intended). Normally, any user with edit privileges should revert such edits.

Comment: In this case, given that you've received both more answers and more detailed answers after the edit than those provided before the edit, it appears that the least harm is done by leaving the question as it currently is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Another time, if you, or anyone with full edit privileges, see question edits which invalidate answers, the general policy is to rollback the edit(s). I understand that in this case you probably only saw that the question was edited after the additional answers were added, which significantly complicates the issue. At that point, it's best to flag for moderator attention and explain the situation. A moderator will attempt to resolve the situation, but, as was the case here, it may be that we have to choose the path that results in least harm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While both values are allowed and perfectly reasonable, that doesn't mean they are interchangeable.

---

Imagine if you wanted Thread 2 to wait for Thread 1 to complete it's work before proceeding. You could use the following:

main:

```c
sem_t sem; 
sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
```

Thread 1:

```
do_work();
sem_post(&sem);
```

Thread 2:

```
do_some_work();

// Wait for Thread 1 to complete before proceeding.
sem_wait(&sem);
do_other_work();
```

As you can see, initializing a semaphore to zero can be perfectly reasonable. That doesn't mean it does the same thing as initializing it to one. Your program is buggy because your thread waits for the value of the semaphore to be raised above zero, but nothing ever does that.

Answer (score 5):

> I am seeing a value of 0 being used in a piece of code. We use a value
> of 1 for a binary semaphore and a value of N for a counting semaphore.
> Somehow the value of 0 isn't making sense to me.

0 is a value that every semaphore can take.  Initializing a semaphore with that value is therefore perfectly reasonable.

> If using either 0 or 1 is fine, then why doesn't this program run [...]

Just because it is reasonable *in general* to initialize a semaphore to zero does not mean that doing so is appropriate for a given particular purpose.

The value of a semaphore at any given time affects its behavior.  In particular, `sem_wait()` attempts to decrement a semaphore without reducing its value below zero, blocking until it can do so.  Thus, if you initialize a semaphore with value zero then every thread that attempts to `sem_wait()` on it will block until some thread increases its value via `sem_post()`.  If you are using the semaphore as a mutex, as the example code does, then you could characterize that as the mutex being initially locked.

Answer (score 2):

The metaphor for a semaphore is a library with N copies of "Moby Dick".  You can only check out N times and then check out waits for a check in.  If you have 1 copy, it behaves like a mutex.  Starting at 0 is just starting locked, a reasonable default.  You can tell it a larger sum before it gets tested.  I would say how, but then I would have to google up the right man pages, which is what I recommend to all my students!  You cannot remember it all, but you should know a little and how to find the rest!  Note that some semaphores live in memory for thread use, others in the file system for inter-process use.

Comment: Thanks David. Reg this statement - "Note that some semaphores live in memory for thread use, others in the file system for inter-process use.". Are they not all in the same memory i..e the stack. is there a distinction in where they reside ?

Comment: Definitely at least a pointer to them either on the heap, or passed, else nobody could find them -- a standard name scope and variable persistence issue!  The machine language for semaphores and mutexes is really kinky.  One CPU I worked on had an instruction to write a word only if that word was zero, with support right down to the core memory subsystem.  A process would try to write its ID there and if if succeeded, it had a lock on whatever it represented, so it was a mutex but might control the values of a semaphore.  It was mostly for OS table access.  Each CPU needs something like that.

Comment: Thanks David. From your comment "Note that some semaphores live in memory for thread use, others in the file system for inter-process use." => which one of this are you referring to as being on the heap and which one as being on the stack ?

Comment: The memory ones can be on heap or stack, it's a pointer passing and name scope question like for any data element.  The file system ones are rooted in shared memory.  It seems possible to root one in mmap()'d file memory, and perhaps they have, as shared memory is somewhat a root administered space.   https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html  and more generally  https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/beginning-linux-programming/9780470147627/9781118058619c14.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

`sem_init` only sets the initial value.
If during the lifetime of the semaphore its value won’t exceed 1, you can call it a binary semaphore, and counting semaphore otherwise.
The initial value is just the first value that the semaphore holds, not the maximum.

Comment: Thanks Dani. I have added an example to the above question where its not possible to have either a 0 or 1 replaceably.

Comment: At the time this answer was posted, the [question was quite different](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63377879/1). At that time, this was a reasonable answer to the question. Unfortunately, the question was substantially edited, which made this answer less valid. Prior to anyone reverting the edits, additional answers were added based on the updated version. Unfortunately, I don't see a *good* resolution here. On balance, the least harm appears to be to leave the question as it currently is. You may choose to update your answer, leave your answer as is, etc.